# Can't Login via OpenID from Mobile Phone?

Tags: openid

Is it that third party authentication in general and OpenID in particular can't be used to login to websites, if I'm on mobile phone?

The reason I ask this is because [buxfer doesn't seem to allow this](https://www.buxfer.com/help.php?topic=Authentication%3aThird_Party_Authentication):

> You will not be able to login to the
>   mobile/iPhone site, Facebook
>   application or Firebux because your
>   password is not stored by Buxfer. To
>   explicitly set a password for your
>   account, login and click on "Settings
>   » Password"

Is it a limitation of the website, or OpenID?

Answer (score 2):

No it is because their mobile/iphone site, facebook application or firebux doesn't support openid as their regular webapp does. I cannot say why or if it is because openid is harder to implement on these platforms but it is not a limitation of the openID format.